# Check the values of max.poll.interval.ms and max.poll.records

Tags: apache-kafka, rebalancing

In order to prevent Kafka rebalancing, I want to increase `max.poll.interval.ms` and decrease `max.poll.records`.
Also, I understand that by default is configured to:

```
max.poll.records = 500
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
```

What I am not sure about is how to check these configurations on an existing instance of the Kafka consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a JVM-based client, then all `ConsumerConfig` properties are printed from log4j upon Consumer instantiation, so ensure your logging client is setup properly.

For any other client, you'd have to dig into the source-code for the defaults, assuming they would be overridden.